# One word for not being a hundred percent transparent

Tags: word-request

I want to say something like "In our team, we are talking *the word I am looking for* ly".
What I want to express is that the communication we are doing is kinda hunk dory , not really talking about the issues that are bothering us. So the communication is not deep enough.

Comment: There are four meanings  "Not 100% transparent"  (ie  not completely clear)  "kinda hunk dory"  (kind of hunky-dory means moderately okay) and "Not talking about the issues" and "not deep enough".  They all mean different things.  Pick one, and that is your answer.  There is a principle "don't use many words when one will do. But don't use one word when you need many to be clear")

Comment: For "not really talking about the issues that are bothering us. So the communication is not deep enough" maybe one of these: Shallowly, frivolously, superficially, trivially, generally,

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Maybe superficially is the word I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, as the opposite of "transparency" is not really what you are looking for. Transparency in communication means *everything* is discussed, or that all information is open and freely available. To say that some information was hidden, or undisclosed suggests some impropriety when it seems all you really want to say is that *you don't communicate effectively*.

Similarly, some of the words suggested in comments like "superficial" imply more than I feel you are asking for. Superficial might suggest a lack of *understanding*, rather than communication.

From my experience in business, people tend to use the expressions "poor communication" or the slightly less pointed "a lack of effective communication" to describe work areas where communication is not achieving all that it should. Where poor communication is caused by a lack of agenda, you might also say your communication or meetings need more *structure*.

I would suggest you say something like:

- our team meetings lack depth.
- our team does not communicate effectively
- our team meetings require more depth
- communication within our team needs more structure

The best approach, especially in business, is to say how something can *improve*, rather than outright criticism, as this can cause offence or have a demotivating effect. Better to say something needs more depth than to say it is shallow.

Answer (score -1):

## Opaque.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/opaque): Opaque (adjective): (especially of language) hard or impossible to understand; unfathomable.
‘technical jargon that was opaque to her’